# How to reconnect to websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm having problems to reconnect to a websocket after the stream is interrupted.

I do not know the root cause why ths stream of data is interrupted. My VPS server is up and running at all time, i have internet access to it, there is another program that runs at the same time and does not have network issues.

But for each packet received I increment my counter i, and if i has not changed for more than 20 seconds, then I try to reconnect. But any code attempts have failed so far, it just loops and tries to reconnect.

Nodejs running on decent linux server. Memory or CPU usage at the time of disconnect is fine. Disconnections have no pattern, sometimes runs for 2 days without problems, sometimes disconnect 4 times per day. When the stream stops, the only way to restart is to exit my code and run it again, and it works immediately, so no problem on server side.

My reconnect code that runs every 20 sec (which is the same as my initial connect code, except for the extra line: const WebSocket = require('ws');

```
//catch broken stream, if i is not changing, close and reconnect and alert through Telegram
if (i == prev_i) {
    ws.terminate();
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('waiting to reconnect');
        const ws = new WebSocket('wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/v2?api_key=6f56....fe10');
        ws.on('open', function open() {
        ws.send('{"action": "SubAdd","subs": ["0~coineal~BTC~USDT"]}');
        });
    }, 10000);


    console.log("Reconnecting to stream");
    var strMessage = "Reconnecting to stream"
    var message = "chat_id=" + strChatId + "&text=" + strMessage
    var request = require('request');
    request.post({
      headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      url:     Url,
      body:    message
    }, function(error, response, body){
    });
}
prev_i = i;
```

edit 5.5.2020:
as per suggestion below, I've modified my code above from

```
const ws = new WebSocket(...
```

to

```
ws = new WebSocket(...
```

Today the stream dropped for the first time since the change. Unfortunately, instead of trying to reconnect in a loop like before, the code execution stopped with the console messages in attached picture. Line 120 is the line that I modified.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem with your code: the `ws` variable is shadowed.

When you do `ws.terminate()` your are terminating the socket held by the `ws` variable in the scope that is in effect around the block of code you quoted. However, in the code you pass to `setTimeout` to create a new socket you do `const ws = new WebSocket(...]`. When you do this, you declare a **new variable in the scope created by the anonymous function you pass to `setTimeout`**. This variable has the same name as the one in the outer scope but **is different** from the one in the outer scope. When you assign to it, the outer scope `ws` is not affected. So the new socket is created, opened and then your code forgets it. So yes, your code will try reconnecting again.

Just dropping the `const` and using `ws = new WebSocket(...)` should work. Obviously, for this to work the `ws` variable defined in the outer scope cannot be declared with `const ws`. It has to be declared with `let ws`, or, not as good, `var ws`.

I would also recommend generally using a linter like [`eslint`](https://eslint.org/) configured with a sensible set of rules. `eslint` has rules to report shadowed variables and prevent shadowing errors.

I would furthermore recommend using something like [PWS](https://github.com/porsager/pws) rather than try to roll your own reconnection code. There are all kinds of edge cases with reconnecting sockets.

Comment: ok, i've implemented the changed to ws = new WebSocket(...). In a couple of days I will report back. As mentioned earlier, the problem does not come every day. Tx.

Comment: Not yet working, please see my edit in my original post.

Comment: The error message suggests to me that the variable in the outer context is declared with `const`. Obviously, if it is `const` then you cannot reassign it. You need to declare it with `let ws` or `var ws`. `var` is ancient technology that comes with a bunch of gotchas. I'd suggest usig `let ws`.

Comment: Inded the first instance was also defined with const. Just copy/pasted it from another place without really understanding it. I've implemented the change now (let ws), let's see how it goes in the coming days. Tx.

Comment: I did not have any disconnect event since the change but as the bounty expires in a few hours and is lost for both of us if not allocated, I marked your answer as solution for now, in recognition for the time you spent on this. As soon as I can validate the modifications you proposed actually solve my problem (or not), I will update this thread.

Comment: Unfortunately today I had a disconnect event, my reconnect code got triggered, but same as before, it loops trying to reconnect.I might give MQTT a try when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using a protocol on top of websockets? This will give you more freedom from these errors and ensure quality of service. One such protocol is MQTT.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt
```